# Subprocess FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2], using Biopythom DSSP

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I wrote the following script.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Bio.PDB import *
p = PDBParser()
structure = p.get_structure("3l40", "C:\\Users\\*\\3l40.pdb")
dssp = DSSP(structure[0], "C:\\Users\\*\\3l40.pdb")
```

Running it, I encounter a problem:

```
File "C:\Users\*\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
startupinfo)
```

I wanted to check which file triggers the error, so I used the pdb debbuger:

```
python.exe -i script.py
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.pm()
> c:\users\*\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py(1224)_execute_child()
-> startupinfo)
```

How to solve the problem?

Python version 3.5.2, Windows 10

Comment: This is unrelated to biopythom dssp, but rather a problem with the Anaconda 3 install where any call to subprocess in Windows will yield this error. I'd be interested in a solution aswell.